# How do I create and store in a property a block that returns a string?

Tags: ios, properties, objective-c-blocks

I'm struggling with the syntax of blocks. I need a block that takes no parameters and returns a string and I need to store that block in a property. So far, this is what I have...

I declare this property:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString * (^myBlockThatReturnsAString) ();
```

I assign the block like this:

```
someObject.myBlockThatReturnsAString = ^NSString * () {
    return @"foo";
};
```

That all compiles fine.

I'm trying use it like this:

```
myString = someObject.myBlockThatReturnsAString;
```

but I get

```
-[__NSMallocBlock__ isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xc16b3b0
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I much prefer understanding it: http://nilsou.com/blog/2013/08/21/objective-c-blocks-syntax/

Comment: @Abizern It's handy but it seems to be only about declaring blocks. According to that page I've declared the property correctly but I still don't understand where I've gone wrong after that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's going wrong is that the way you are attempting to run the block doesn't actually run it, it just returns the block object and attempts to assign it to an `NSString` variable.

This should work:

`myString = someObject.myBlockThatReturnsAString();`

Here is a [great article](http://nilsou.com/blog/2013/08/21/objective-c-blocks-syntax/) about understanding the block syntax and why it is the way it is.

Comment: Thank you Benoit for the explanation. It makes sense. However, when I add the parentheses I get EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xc). So maybe the new question is how to execute a block stored in a property when the block takes no parameters?

Comment: How did you assign the block to the property? Also, are you using ARC?

Comment: Yes, ARC (Xcode 5, iOS7, same behaviour in iOS6). Assigning as above.

Comment: In your example, what is the type of the pointer that receives the `isEqualToString` message? (0xc16b3b0 in the example)

Comment: I'm not sure how to find out. In the console I type po __NSMallocBlock__ but it just returns. (when I save this comment the double underscores on either side get removed)

Comment: (You can put backticks ` around comments to make them use the code font) What if when you declare the block you assign it to a local variable, and then assign the local variable to the property? Similarly, what if you assign the property to a local block variable and execute that?

Comment: `(lldb) po [__NSMallocBlock__ class]` returns `__NSMallocBlock__`
Does that help?

Comment: Here's one thing. I changed the block declaration to take a string and changed the assignment to match. Then I used it like this `myString = someObject.myBlockThatReturnsAString(@"");` and it works.

Comment: I have no idea what I did but your answer is now working. I'll mark it as the answer and I'm going to remove some of the edit's I made to my question so that it's closer to the original.